# How do I change the content in the Drupal 8 full-calendar dialog

Tags: drupal-8, fullcalendar-4

I am using the [Full Calendar View Plugin](https://www.drupal.org/project/fullcalendar_view) (via [Smart Date Calendar Kit](https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_date_calendar_kit)) on Drupal 9 and I do not see any way to manage the dialog/popup content displayed after clicking an event.

The dialog displays.  Initially, it just displayed the date (no body/description as you'd expect).  Then I added a new field to the entity and now it only displays that field (no date, no body/description).

I have reviewed the limited documentation (shown on the attached links), but have not been able to find this information.

I'm looking for hooks or services I can override.  It looks like I may be able to override fullcalendar_view.view_preprocess, but it seems like this should be easier (  What's the point of having the dialog-option if you can't control what displays in it).  Perhaps the intent is to override the JS settings, idk.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the **best** solution, but it works and puts the dialog content back to the rendering API so we can use view modes.

Hook into the view...

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_view_alter().
 *
 * @param array $build
 * @param BlockPluginInterface $block
 * @return void
 */
function MYMODULE_block_view_alter(array &$build, BlockPluginInterface $block) {
  switch ($block->getPluginId()) {
    case 'views_block:events_calendar-event_cal_block': // ADJUST TO YOUR BLOCK REFERENCE
      $build['#pre_render'][] = function(array $build) {
        $rendered_dialog_content = [];
        $view_builder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node');
        $renderer = \Drupal::service('renderer');
        foreach($build['content']['view_build']['#rows'] as $index => $subview) {
          /** @var ResultRow $row */
          foreach ($subview['#rows'] as $row) {
            $result_build = $view_builder->view($row->_entity, 'dialog'); // YOUR VIEW MODE
            $rendered_dialog_content[$row->_entity->id() . '-' . $index] = $renderer->render($result_build, FALSE);
          }
          $build['content']['#attached']['library'][] = 'MYMODULE/calendar-dialog';
          $build['content']['#attached']['drupalSettings']['calendarDialogEvents'] = $rendered_dialog_content;
        }
        return $build;
      };
      break;
  }
```

Add MYMODULE/calendar-dialog library: MYMODULE.libraries.yml

```
calendar-dialog:
  js:
      js/calendar-dialog.js: {}
```

Add Drupal behavior: js/calendar-dialog.js

```
/* global Drupal */
/* global drupalSettings */

(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {

    'use strict';

    /**
     * Update calendar-options-events-des metadata with rendered content.
     *
     * @type {Drupal~behavior}
     */
    Drupal.behaviors.updateCalendarOptions = {
        attach: function () {

            $(document).once('updateCalendarOptions').each(() => {

                let fullcalendarInstances = $('.js-drupal-fullcalendar'),
                    dialogEvents = drupalSettings.calendarDialogEvents;

                if (
                    typeof fullcalendarInstances !== "object" ||
                    fullcalendarInstances.length === 0 ||
                    typeof dialogEvents !== "object" ||
                    dialogEvents.length === 0
                ) {
                    return;
                }

                fullcalendarInstances.each(function() {
                    let calendarEl = this,
                        viewIndex = parseInt(calendarEl.getAttribute("calendar-view-index")),
                        viewSettings = drupalSettings.fullCalendarView[viewIndex],
                        calendarOptions = JSON.parse(viewSettings.calendar_options);

                    calendarOptions.events.forEach((calEvent, i) => {
                       let nid = calEvent.eid.split('-')[0],
                           dei = nid + '-' + viewIndex;
                       if (dialogEvents.hasOwnProperty(dei)) {
                           calendarOptions.events[i].des = dialogEvents[dei];
                       }
                    });

                    drupalSettings.fullCalendarView[viewIndex].calendar_options = JSON.stringify(calendarOptions);

                });
            });
        }
    };

})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

If there is a better solution, please let me know.